# Highcharts Stacked column Chart in grouped format

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, highcharts

I need to design the same below image chart example in Highchart.js which is built in excel. Can anyone please help me to develop this in highcharts.js only like the below image?

[Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJGMO.png)

I already have implemented it in a similar way. But I need this in a different group of colors and combinations in the same chart. -

```
    `https://jsfiddle.net/shwetapandey/rwmxoka5`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to add new series, with different xAxis, [series.columnrange.xAxis](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.xAxis). To styling you have options to adjust like [xAxis.left](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.left) and [xAxis.top](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.top).

```
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
  },
  xAxis: [{
    width: '33%',
    offset: 0,
  }, {
    left: '50%',
    width: '33%',
    offset: 0,
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    columnrange: {
      grouping: false,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Joe',
      color: '#E5DDE3',
      data: [
        [-5, 5],
        [-10, 10],
        [-13, 13],
        [-16, 16],
        [-19, 19]
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane',
      color: '#BEA9BA',
      data: [
        [-3.5, 3.5],
        [-6, 6],
        [-7, 7],
        [-9, 9],
        [-12, 12]
      ]
    },
    {
      color: '#A5879E',
      name: 'John',
      data: [
        [-1.5, 1.5],
        [-2, 2],
        [-3, 3],
        [-4, 4],
        [-5, 5]
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Joe1',
      color: '#FFA500',
      xAxis: 1,
      data: [
        [-5, 5],
        [-10, 10],
        [-13, 13],
        [-16, 16],
        [-19, 19]
      ].reverse()
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane1',
      color: '#FFA500',
      xAxis: 1,
      data: [
        [-3.5, 3.5],
        [-6, 6],
        [-7, 7],
        [-9, 9],
        [-12, 12]
      ]
    },
    {
      color: '#FFA500',
      name: 'John1',
      xAxis: 1,
      data: [
        [-1.5, 1.5],
        [-2, 2],
        [-3, 3],
        [-4, 4],
        [-5, 5]
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cpjgvds9/

To control each series you need to write a custom legend control, for this you can use [legend.labelFormatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter), that give you callback function to format each of the series' labels.

EDIT ------

To control many group series I used callback function [events.legendItemClick](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.events.legendItemClick) builded in series events. They give way to manage series at legend in that case I compare name of series and index of items to hide and show group of series with custom legend.

```
  events: {
    legendItemClick: function() {
      let name = this.name.substring(this.name.length - 1, this.name.length);

      let _i = this._i;
      this.chart.series.forEach(function(p, i) {
        console.log('p: ', p, 'i: ', i);
        if (name === p.name.substring(p.name.length - 1, p.name.length) && _i !== p._i) {
          (!p.visible) ? p.show(): p.hide()
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v0kt5b14

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian, that's exactly what I was looking for. But can you please help me with the `legend` also? I just want a custom `legend` for each color group. Just check this example in the image that has the `legend`. [Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJGMO.png)

Comment: To control many group series I used callback function events.legendItemClick builded in series events. They give way to manage series at legend in that case I compare name of series and index of items to hide and show group of series with custom legend.

Comment: The click is not working properly in my case. Even in your jsfiddle it falls to memory leak. Can you update my code in jsfiddle with the suggestion that you just suggested?

https://jsfiddle.net/shwetapandey/rwmxoka5/6/

But anyways.. I really appreciate your support. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I edited example that you shared https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v0kt5b14/